# Was there a special Sabbath in addition to Passover when Jesus was crucified?

Tags: crucifixion, calendar

My question is based on John 19:31 which says that on the day Jesus died it was the day of Preparation, and the next day was to be a special Sabbath.  Was this special Sabbath (on which no work could be done) the first day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread?

If so then Nisan 14 would have been Preparation Day for the Feast of Unleavened Bread and Jesus’ body would have had to be laid in the tomb before sundown on that day – but that would not have been the weekly Sabbath that commenced at sundown on Friday.  It would have been the special Sabbath for the start of the Feast of Unleavened Bread.

Here is what I found, but I can’t source the information or get verification for the claims:

> “Some years before the birth of Jesus the Passover celebration had been changed and in the Lord’s time called for a brief ritual meal of lamb, unleavened bread, and bitter herbs to begin the 14th Nisan followed by a great and leisurely festival meal on the 15th, when the Feast of Unleavened Bread begins. This tradition is still followed today.  The 14th became known as Preparation Day (Mark 15:42, Luke 23:54, John 19:31), because on it they made ready for the great feast day beginning at sundown, after which no work was permitted. Matthew identifies the day after the Crucifixion as the day after Preparation Day (27:62) so all four Gospels agree. Jesus died on Preparation day, the 14th of their month Nisan, which is Passover. He ate the ritual meal with His disciples in the Upper Room, and then was arrested, tried, convicted, and put to death; all on Passover.”

Was the special Sabbath mentioned in John 19:31 and Matthew 27:62 the start of the Feast of Unleavened Bread?  And is there any evidence to support that view?

Comment: The quote seems to come from a 2003 Jack Kelley study, https://gracethrufaith.com/topical-studies/holidays-and-holy-days/solving-the-three-day-three-night-mystery/

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/35825/23657.  I found this answer interesting though it does not specifically answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes; the high Sabbath was the first day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread on the 15th Nisan.  I've written a 92,000 word manuscript looking for a publisher on the days/dates of Christ's death, burial, resurrection issues, but will summarize just your specific question.  This is not to say that the web site reference from which the OP is drawn is correct.  It's not.  For example, there's no evidence of a "brief ritual meal of lamb ... " as the 14th began at sunset.

> John 19:31 The Jews therefore, because it was the preparation, that the bodies should not remain upon the cross on the sabbath day, (for that sabbath day was an **high** day,) besought Pilate that their legs might be broken, and that they might be taken away.

The word translated "high" is the Greek megas.  It is translated usually as great, loud.  Thus earlier in John we read about another high/great/megas day.

> John 7:37 In the last day, that **great** day of the feast, Jesus stood and cried, saying, If any man thirst, let him come unto me, and drink.

That megas reference is about John 7:1 at the feast of tabernacles.  It too was a type of Sabbath as defined way back in time.

> Lev. 23:3 Six days shall work be done: but the seventh day is the sabbath of rest, an holy convocation; ye shall do no work therein: it is the sabbath of the LORD in all your dwellings.

The Sabbath was a holy convocation; no work.  So, we take that to find what John references about the megas last day of Feast of Tabernacles and first day of Unleavened Bread.

> Lev. 23:36 Seven days ye shall offer an offering made by fire unto the LORD: on the eighth day [the last day] shall be an holy convocation unto you; and ye shall offer an offering made by fire unto the LORD: it is a solemn assembly; and ye shall do no servile work therein.

That Feast Sabbath is a high Sabbath.  There are seven.  And so, we apply the same terminology to the first day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread.

> Lev. 23:7 In the first day [of Unleavened Bread] ye shall have an holy convocation: ye shall do no servile work therein.

With that in mind, we return to John 19:31.  Christ was crucified on Passover the 14th of Nisan the preparation day and the next day was the high Sabbath first day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread on the 15th.

But what of Mt. 27:62?  This answer requires much more background to explain adequately.

> Now the next day, that followed the day of the preparation, the chief priests and Pharisees came together unto Pilate,

On the surface, I would suggest it doesn't matter whether it refers to Friday or Saturday when they visit Pilate.  It doesn't contradict anything either way.  If it was Friday afternoon the day after Passover preparation, then they were still looking to seal the tomb three days from burial to Sunday.  If it was Saturday the day after the weekly Friday preparation, then they were still looking to seal the tomb three days from burial to Sunday.  Again to clarify, this is not to say that the chief priests understood prophecies properly, they just understood burial as a starting day and wanted the tomb sealed.

Comment: Many thanks for your input and insights, which I appreciate. We know the tomb was empty early on the first day of the week (which corresponds to our Sunday) and that's the important part.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's an interesting study the days/dates.  Yes, the tomb was empty that Sunday the 17th of Nisan.

Comment: @SLM is this manuscript publically available or on its way soon? I saw you were looking for a publisher, but just wondering what if you had it somewhere already or what.

Comment: @AlexStrasser  Thanks for asking, but no success with the "regular" publishers.  I'll have to self-publish, which I hope to accomplish 2020.

Comment: 2020 come and gone.

Comment: @SLM A user is [asking for your 92,000 word manuscript](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/85862/10672).  Did you have success on having it published?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple  thank you for the heads up.  As mentioned, I'll probably have to self-publish.

Answer (score 5):

We in the western world have been raised in a culture dominated by a post-Constantinian Christian worldview of time, rather than one that is biblically Hebrew.

1. Our days begin and end at midnight, rather than the biblical
   breaking point of sunset.
2. Our days are named after celestial bodies and Norse gods revered in
   pagan worship and our work week begins on Monday and ends with a day
   of rest on Sunday (the first day of the week), rather than
   continuing the biblical pattern that Jesus and His disciples adhered
   to of keeping Sabbath on the seventh day.
3. Our Gregorian calendar years are numbered from the birth of Christ,
   rather than from the traditional Hebrew reckoning of the beginning
   of creation.
4. We have replaced the biblically instituted feasts of Pesach
   (Passover), Shavuot, Rosh Hashanah, Yom Kippur, and Sukkot
   celebrated by the people of Israel with a variety of newly-minted
   Christian seasons like Advent and Lent and holy days like Christmas
   and Easter, as well as secular and neo-pagan holidays (holy days?)
   like New Year’s Day, Memorial Day, Independence Day, Labor Day,
   Halloween, and Thanksgiving.

Rediscovering the worldview and timeframe of Christianity's Hebrew heritage allows us to more fully appreciate the activities of Jesus of Nazareth at the time of His earthly ministry, crucifixion, death, and resurrection.

The first month of the Hebrew calendar is the month of Nisan, which starts at the dawn of spring. On Nisan 10 every year, our spiritual forefathers were mandated in Scripture to select a Passover lamb without blemish, observe the lamb for three days for signs of unworthiness, and sacrifice it on the fourth day as a ceremonial beginning to the celebration of the Lord’s Passover and the Exodus of God’s people from slavery in Egypt. Passover has been celebrated for millennia by the house of Israel in a traditional order or Seder on the evening of Nisan 15. In the year He was crucified, Jesus rode into Jerusalem on a donkey on Nisan 10, taught publicly in the Temple for three days before being sacrificed on the cross on Nisan 14, and was placed in the tomb just as the Passover feast was about to begin.

How long did Jesus stay in the “heart of the earth” before He was raised from the dead? Jesus answered our question Himself in Matthew 12.38-40.

How does His prophetic answer match up with the rest of Scripture and our gentile Good Friday, Easter Sunday tradition?
 How did Jesus’ calendar match up with ours?
One attempt to solve this Passover puzzle can be found in the [chart linked here](http://hb-community.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Fulfillment.pdf) “Jesus Fulfills the Promise of Passover,” which places the Last Supper Seder on the Tuesday evening of Preparation Day followed by His crucifixion and burial on Wednesday afternoon just prior to the start of the annual Passover Sabbath celebration that evening.

He then spent three days and nights in the tomb as He promised and rose from the grave after sundown on Saturday evening in time for the tomb to be found empty Sunday morning. What is your solution? Read the Gospel accounts of Jesus final days (Matthew chapters 21-28; Mark 11-16; Luke 19-24; John 12-20) and map out your own timeline.

Comment: Thank you for your input, which I appreciate.  Also for your latest question which deserves a considered response.

Comment: Excellent and very thorough explanation, Bill M.  All other  alleged scenarios are all built on a flawed understanding of Jewish history and culture and "Sabbaths", and the result is that it requires people to throw out the clear words of scripture and Christ himself .  Only a Wed Crucifixion can harmonize the women buying spices after the Sabbath, the Roman seal for 3 days, and Christ's only sign that He is in fact the Messiah - Sign of Jonah 3 days and 3 nights.

Comment: The problem with a Wednesday death and burial scenario is it ignores the fact that would be day 1, as counted before sunset.  You can't ignore days, even as some "add" days (Fri-Sun).  Some believe Jesus died and was buried Wed-1, Thur-2, Fri-3, Sat-4, and rose on Sun-5.  It is impossible and certainly doesn't fulfill the sign of Jonah.

Comment: SLM, your research looks very very fascinating.  I would love to find out more about it, or how to get a copy.   The Wed crucifix is the only scenario that resolves all the scripture and also eliminates the glitches.  You don't count Sun as part of a day.  You also don't count Wed. It's Wed sunset, to Saturday sunset= 3 days and 3 nights. The women bought spices after the sabbath - high sabbath Wednes night & Thurs day [Friday] and before the weekly Sabbath. Impossible to buy spices after dark on Saturday night.  Also Roman guard was 3 days. Frid Cruc means it was only there 1/2 day -Saturday.

Comment: @Tennman7 I understand trying to "move" the facts to sunset, but, he said Christ died and buried before sunset on Wednesday.  As you point out, some try to "add" days/nights, but others try to "subtract" days/nights.  IMO, the answer is clearly about what was meant by "heart of the earth".  Some believed it meant the tomb and then tried to justify the shortfall by saying (rightly in some cases) that a part of a day counts as a full day/night in Jewish understanding.  Some don't count all the days.  Others, including myself, believe it refers to the period from sufferings (Passover) to glory.

Comment: I'm not following you SLM.  Christ said in the heart of the earth - It's not the time when he was on the cross.  It's those who false try to use "Jewish Inclusive Reckoning" in the crucifixion, because they don't understand Jewish culture and feast days, so they have to twist things , & they count the fraction of the day on Friday, but they also count Sund morn. It's 1 1/2 days. Jewish Inclusive reckoning does not apply here, or in Jonah. It's out the window.   I'm quite sure, SLM that you would agree that you don't believe Jonah was in the belly of the great fish a day and a half, amiright?

Comment: @Tennman7  "as" Jonah was.  How?  Alive or dead or both over the 3 nights/days?  Then Jonah prayed unto the LORD his God out of the fish's belly,   Psalm 74:12 For God is my King of old, working salvation in the midst [heart] of the earth.  When?.  Isa 53:5 But he was wounded for our transgressions, he was bruised for our iniquities: the chastisement of our peace was upon him; and with his stripes we are healed.  From sufferings to glory in the heart of the earth.  Sunset 14th Passover as Wed ends and Thur begins night 1, day 1, night 2, day 2, night 3, day 3 sunset sabbath ends sunday begins.

Comment: SLM, the last sentence is correct.  3 days and 3 nights. Wed sunset to Saturday sunset. Women came in the night - start of Sunday.  He was already gone. But you didn't answer my ? Do you believe the scripture that Jonah was in the fish 3 days & 3 nights? Or do you believe it was 1 day and a half.? [parts of 2 days] Women rested on High Sab- thursday, bought spices Friday" - "after the sabbath" and rested on Weekly Sabbath. No unsolvable issues. Frid crucifixion means people have to twist scrip- & not accept what scripture & Christ plainly said bc they don't understand Hebrew feasts & culture.

Comment: Jonah was in the belly 3 days/nights, but he wasn't dead and buried, unlike the idea that heart of the earth is the tomb (dead and buried).  Thur-Sat is 3 days/nights with Thur beginning sunset our Wed.  Passover the 14th a Thur, First day Feast the 15th Fri, Sabbath day/night 3.  Sunset to sunset from sufferings to glory, working salvation in the heart (quereb) of the earth.  As to women and spices, they bought the spices the day after weekly sabbath on the 10th sunday.  Great contrast between triumphal entry as king and preparation for burial as suffering servant.  They prepare on 15th.

Comment: The "chart linked here" is broken.

Comment: One thing that I haven't seen mentioned (forgive me if it has been), is that they were in a big rush to get Christ entombed before the Sabbath (sundown Wednesday).  If they had to rush, it's likely that Christ was entombed pretty darn close to sunset, which means you don't have to add/subtract or otherwise rationalize partial days ... given no evidence to the contrary, I'd say he was placed in the tomb at sunset, just in time, and was resurrected at sundown 3 nights and days later.  No adjustments needed.

Comment: Nisan 15 was not a Sabbath when the Hebrew Scriptures were written. Originally, the weekly Sabbath and the Day of Atonement (Yom Kippur) were called Sabbaths in the Hebrew Scriptures and forbade *all* work while the other six annual holy convocations forbade only *servile* work and were not called Sabbaths. For more details, see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/62640/can-nisan-15-be-referred-to-as-the-sabbath/78614#78614

Answer (score 1):

**Was the special Sabbath mentioned in John 19:31 and Matthew 27:62 the start of the Feast of Unleavened Bread?**

Yes, John 19:31 reads:

> The Jews therefore, because it was the preparation, that the bodies should not remain upon the cross on the sabbath day, (for that sabbath day was an high day,) besought Pilate that their legs might be broken, and that they might be taken away.

Here are a few facts you can find in any encyclopedia:

- Biblical days are measured from sunset to sunset.
- Passover begins on the eve of Nissan 15 (after sunset on the 14th), with a seder and roast lamb meal.
- The day of Passover is a high holiday, a full sabbath.
- The first day of Passover (the 15th) is never on a Monday, Wednesday, or Friday.
- On Passover day and during the next week (Days of Unleavened Bread), all yeast products are forbidden and must be removed from everyone's houses before sunset.
- No work is allowed on a sabbath day, whether a high holiday or a weekly sabbath.

So, since nothing could be done after sunset at the end of the 14th, a lot of activity has to happen before then:

- Clean the house to remove all traces of yeast.
- Make the evening meal, plus meals to eat during the next day.
- All housework to get things ready for the celebration.
- The afternoon slaughter of the lambs for the Passover meal.

For obvious reasons, the 14th became known as the "Day of Preparation".  It has no specific religious significance, but is tied to the high holiday that follows it.

The John 19:31 verse describes an instance of this need for urgent activity.  Burying a dead body is considered work.  If Jesus and the two thieves hadn't died soon enough, they would have had to remain there for another 36 hours until the morning after the high sabbath when their bodies could be removed.  They weren't given permission until the 11th hour, an hour before sunset, so the burial had to be done very quickly so that people could return to their homes by sunset.

We know from Mark 16:1 ("*when the sabbath was past [they] bought sweet spices*") and Luke 23:56 ("*[they] prepared spices and ointments and rested the sabbath day*"), that there were two sabbaths shortly after Jesus's crucifixion.  The women waited until after the high sabbath to buy and prepare spices the next day, and then waited until after the normal weekly sabbath to take them to the tomb.

The weekly sabbath is always from the sunset at the end of Friday until the sunset at the end of Saturday.  Thus, early Sunday morning (John 20:1 "*The first day of the week ...*") was the first chance they had to go to the tomb.

That means that:

- The weekly sabbath was on Saturday.
- The spices were bought and prepared the day before, on Friday.
- The high holiday sabbath was the day before,on Thursday.
- The Day of Preparation was the day before, on Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus said

> Matt 12:40: For as Jonah was in the belly of the great fish for three days and three nights, so will the Son of Man be in the heart of the earth for three days and three nights. (NLT)

We must be true in all our explanations to what He said. So however we explain the days/dates, the idea of the 'High Sabbath' comes closest to Jesus' words about Himself. I have believed it for years.

Answer (score 0):

Lesley, Your question is excellent and you are correct.

"My question is based on John 19:31 which says that on the day Jesus died it was the day of Preparation, and the next day was to be a special Sabbath. Was this special Sabbath (on which no work could be done) the first day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread?"

**Yes, on both counts**. Passover is the 14th of Nisan, the 15th of Nisan starts the Feast of Unleavened bread, but since they are back to back and the feast of Unleavened bread lasts 7 days, they all get lumped together as Passover.

This is very significant, because this is exactly what the reason for so much confusion and misinformation about the crucifixion - most Christians today don't understand Jewish culture, or Jewish calendars, or Feast days.

Another very important thing that most Christians don't realize is that in the Hebrew language, *Shabbat* is the word for Sabbath, but all the 7 feasts and the weekly sabbath are Shabbat.  Passover is a feast day, but it's not a High Sabbath day - in which all work is forbidden. Slaughtering a lamb, cleaning it and roasting it is a lot of work, and Passover is the preparation day for Feast of Unleavened Bread - in which no work could be done.  Church leaders incorrectly assumed that this was Friday - preparation for the weekly sabbath.

Regarding your second question, Lesley, yes, there is evidence, it is clearly in the gospel account itself, and also in the Old Testament Torah, specifically Leviticus, where the feasts are given along with the specific commands about how they are to be kept.
https://www.gotquestions.org/high-Sabbath.html "So Jesus was crucified on the day before a high Sabbath. Because the Jews did not want Jerusalem desecrated on such a holy day as a high Sabbath, they petitioned the governor that the bodies of Jesus and those crucified with Him be taken down before evening (see Deuteronomy 21:22–23).

Scripture explicitly says that there were two Sabbaths in Christ's final week.  The High Sabbath being Nisan 15 [Wed sundown -Thursday day] ** Remember Jewish days go sundown to sundown - Evening and Day. Jews used a Lunar calendar, and the cool thing is that the new moon is the start of every month, and because Passover is always the 14th of Nisan, it means Passover is always on a full moon.  The Pharisees asked Christ for a sign that he really was the Messiah, and he only gave one sign and this was the sign of Jonah, which Christ quoted in Matthew.

> "Just as Jonah was 3 days and 3 nights in the belly of the great fish, so the son of man will be 3 days and 3 nights in the heart of the earth."

Scripture says that the women bought rested on the sabbath and bought spices after the sabbath.

This is impossible to buy spices after dark on Saturday night - after the weekly Sabbath. They rested on High Sabbath - Thursday, bought spices on Friday, after the High Sabbath, and before the weekly Sabbath.
In the 1st century, the only light besides the sun and moon were candles and torches. Buying and selling was forbidden on Sabbaths.  So the idea of buying spices after sunset on Saturday night is patently absurd.  No one would go set up their goods to sell in the dark, after the Sabbath had ended.
So they rested on the High Sabbath-feast of Unleavened bread- Thursday. Bought spices on Friday, and then rested on the weekly sabbath.

This is also why they had to get the bodies down from the cross before the high Sabbath - Feast of unleavened Bread. Wednesday at sunset to Saturday at Sunset is 3 days and 3 nights - just like Jesus himself said.
The other interesting thing is that we have 3 separate accounts of people being dead for at least 3 full days and nights, and raising again. Lazarus, Jesus, and the 2 witnesses in Revelation. This is because according to Jewish world view, and burial customs - the spirit lingers near the body for 3 days - so they would not be fully dead, but in a coma. After 3 days, the soul or spirit leaves so there they would be truly dead, and no one would say they were in a coma, and thus- no chance of resurrecting. This is what makes the resurrection so amazing.

Either we can trust the words Christ said, and the only sign he gave that he was the Messiah, or we can't.  It's impossible to get 3 days and 3 nights from 1 day and parts of 2 days.  It also requires that we totally disregard the clear words of scripture and even the words of Christ himself and a Friday crucifixion cannot answer the problem of the spices and 3 days and 3 nights.

An excellent summary and solid explanation with charts is here on blue letter Bible. https://www.blueletterbible.org/faq/crux.cfm

Comment: FYI, there is no history that supports the idea that the 14th was a Tuesday.  IOW, it is a recent idea.

Comment: There is a problem. The first day of Unleavened Bread, Nisan 15 was not called a Sabbath in the Hebrew Scriptures. In Leviticus 23 there are the holy convocations (assemblies) listed. The weekly Sabbaths and the seven annual holy days are all holy convocations. But only the weekly Sabbath and Day of Atonement are called Sabbaths in the Hebrew Scriptures. The Sabbaths allow *no* work while the other 6 annual holy convocations forbid only *servile* work and are not called Sabbaths. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/62640/can-nisan-15-be-referred-to-as-the-sabbath/78614#78614

Answer (score -1):

Jesus said 3 days in the tomb.  Friday to Sunday is not 3 days.  The Hebrew day starts at sundown. Wednesday at 6 starts first night (Thursday), etc.

Comment: We prefer longer, well thought out responses, backed up with sources.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I hope you will explore our tour and help center to learn more about us and how we do things around here. We like to be detailed in thorough in our responses. Therefore, please provide detail and external sources. This answer provides no new information.